Fairy Tale where parents have dozens of kids and give them all the same name
I remember reading a fairy tale (I think it would be described as a fairy tale, but I could be misremembering something more like a nursery rhyme) about some foolish parents who had many children and gave them all the same name so they wouldn't have to remember each one. I don't remember what the name was, and I don't remember at all what the payoff to this story was or if it was like a "wouldn't that be messed up" type deal.

While certainly not the correct answer, this reminds me of the Igors in Terry Pratchett's Discworld.

From ‘Too Many Daves’ by Dr. Seuss:

Did I ever tell you that Mrs. McCave
Had twenty-three sons and she named them all Dave?
Well, she did. And that wasn’t a smart thing to do.
You see, when she wants one and calls out, “Yoo-Hoo!
Come into the house, Dave!” she doesn’t get one.
All twenty-three Daves of hers come on the run!
‘Dr. Seuss’ [Theodor Seuss Geisel] (1961). ‘Too Many Daves’. In The Sneetches and Other Stories, pages 36–38. New York: Random House.


IRL, boxer George Foreman named all 5 of his sons George. But his 7 daughters all have distinct names. The sons also have nicknames, that's presumably how they avoided Mrs. McCave's conundrum.

@Barmar In certain parts of the US it is/was normal to name all male sons with the same first name (such as their maternal grandfather's name,) and call them by their middle name.

@JimmyJames They all have the same middle name, too. They're distinguished with Jr, III, IV, etc.

@Barmar Huh. That's a little unusual, I think. I wonder if any of those Georges will follow that tradition.  E.g., George 3.1?

@JimmyJames Indeed, it's very ideosyncratic. His wikipedia page has his explanation.
